# md5 hash throwing an error in PHP

Tags: php, md5

md5 hash throwing an error in PHP

( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant md5 - assumed 'md5' in
         C:\wamp\www\sva2\php\register.php on line 22
    Call Stack
    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
    1   0.0115  381992  {main}( )   ..\register.php:0

```
    <?php
require 'ChromePhp.php';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
 $dbuser = 'root'; // $dbuser = 'root'
 $dbpass = '';     // $dbpass = ''
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, 'ss');
// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    ChromePhp::log("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 $username = $_GET['username'];
 $password = $_GET['password'];
 $confirmpassword = $_GET['password_confirm'];
 ChromePhp::log($username);
 //ChromePhp::log($password);

 if($username != "")
 {
 $mdsh = $username.'';
 $mdhash = md5($mdsh);


   }

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with the provided code. Please show us your **exact** error message and your **full** and **real** code

Comment: Now since you show the exact error message the code still doesn't produce this error (In no php version). Show us your full script from `register.php`. Your error is in line 22 but you show us 6 lines of code.

Comment: Please list with line numbers.  What line is #22?  Also fyi it's very unprofessional to use curse words as variable names.

Comment: Create another php file with just the following line, to ensure md5 is working.  Let us know the output. <?php echo md5("test"); ?>

Comment: @RyanGriggs works fine in a seperate file

Comment: @happs Is this file: `register.php` ? Also mark line 22 with a comment, right now it's just a empty line here

Comment: Charset used? Possible hidden characters?  Also, could the chromephp file be causing this?

Comment: @RyanGriggs Thanks It was because of ChromePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to ensure the chromephp include isn't causing this.